# Methods to manipulate a single character within a specific column of a DataFrame in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, apply

I am seeking ways to manipulate the last character of the string found within a specific column of a dataframe based on key-value pairs I have created in a dictionary. I need the letter character shown in the dataframe below to be changed to the value that corresponds in the dictionary (IE in line 0 the data point would change to "0000000027581"). Any input would be appreciated!

DataFrame:

```
Column 1
0   000000002758A
1   000000326588B
2  0000000000000{
```

Dictionary:

```
Key = {"{":"0", "A":"1", "B":"2"}
```

Comment: Here a simila problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850192/python-extract-last-digit-of-a-string-from-a-pandas-column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method of series [str](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)
available only for object dtype

```
df['Column 1'].str[-1]
```

do the job

Answer (score 0):

Join everything up to the final character with the final character mapped with your dictionary.

```
Key = {"{":"0", "A":"1", "B":"2"}

df['Column 1'] = df['Column 1'].str[:-1] + df['Column 1'].str[-1].replace(Key)

print(df)
         Column 1
0   0000000027581
1   0000003265882
2  00000000000000
```